# Bootstrap media object - media body content wraps around image

Tags: bootstrap-5

I would like to use Bootstrap's [media object](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/media-object/#example), however, it doesn't seem to work.
If I copy-paste their example code (or any other examples, e.g. from w3school's tutorial) the media body content is **never** positioned **alongside** the image, but it **always** goes **under** it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="media">
  <img class="mr-3" src="..." alt="Generic placeholder image">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-0">Media heading</h5>
    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[media body content under the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKopT.png)

The interesting thing is that even if I try a similar code from any code playgrounds (where they work properly) I have the same issue...

Does anyone have similar experiences with Bootstrap's media object??
What am I doing wrong...?

Thanks.

(PS: Bootstrap is loaded = CSS linked, JS script tag included.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using Bootstrap v5.2.1(included CSS + JS), but your are try use the `.media` element that only available on Bootstrap v4.

In Bootstrap v5.2, You can use [`.row`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/columns/) and `.col` to implement it.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3"><img class="mr-3" src="..." alt="Generic placeholder image"></div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <h5 class="mt-0">Media heading</h5>
    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
  </div>
</div>
```